# C++ Passing pointer to function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pass-by-reference, pointer-to-array

OK i have a function

```
    int main
{
   ....
   char *wordl=word();//wordl pointer is an array of characters
   ...
   gamewindow(wordl,length);
}


void gamewindow(char &wordl,int length);
```

My question is how to pass pointer such that passed pointer points to the same array list..
and i can access it by wordl[i] in gamewindow function.

From the comment below, implementation of `word()`:

```
   char* word() 
    { int j=1988497762; cout<<j<<endl ; 
    static char original[25]; 
    int x;
     ifstream fin("out.txt"); 
    for (j=0;!fin.eof();j++) 
    fin.getline(original,25); 
    fin.close(); 
    srand ( (unsigned) time(NULL) ); 
    x = rand()%j; cout<<x<<"\n"; 
    cout<<rand()<<endl; 
    char c; 
    ifstream finn("out.txt"); 
    for (j=0; !finn.eof(); j++)
     { finn>>c; finn.getline(original,25); if (x==j) break; } 
    finn.close(); 
    return original; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use it like this only (and not use `std::vector` or `std::string`) you need change `gamewindow` to `void gamewindow(char *wordl,int length);` Then you can access `char` using `word1[i]`.

Comment: tried that... but while passing the pointer it just makes a copy of itself.    hence wordl[i] has some garbage value ...

Comment: @ABC: It should work assuming `word()` returns a dynamically allocated memory and not from stack. Can you show implementation of `word()`?

Comment: @ABC
<pre><code>   char* word()
{
 int j=1988497762;
 cout<<j<<endl ;
 static char original[25];
    int x;
 ifstream fin("out.txt"); for (j=0;!fin.eof();j++)   fin.getline(original,25);
 fin.close();
    srand ( (unsigned) time(NULL) );
     x = rand()%j;
     cout<<x<<"\n";
  cout<<rand()<<endl;
 char c;
    ifstream finn("out.txt");
 for (j=0; !finn.eof(); j++) {
    finn>>c;
    finn.getline(original,25);
    if (x==j) break;
   }
   finn.close();
   return original;
}
</code></pre>

Answer (score 2):

Better use `std::string`, `std::vector` and other standard [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/). If on C++2011, use perhaps [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

So declare instead

```
 void gamewindow(std::string&str);
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: <pre><code>    char* word()
{
 int j=1988497762;
 cout<<j<<endl ;
 static char original[25];
    int x;
 ifstream fin("out.txt"); for (j=0;!fin.eof();j++)   fin.getline(original,25);
 fin.close();
    srand ( (unsigned) time(NULL) );
     x = rand()%j;
     cout<<x<<"\n";
  cout<<rand()<<endl;
 char c;
    ifstream finn("out.txt");
 for (j=0; !finn.eof(); j++) {
    finn>>c;
    finn.getline(original,25);
    if (x==j) break;
   }
   finn.close();
   return original;
}
</code><pre>